# get value from json to angularjs object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I want to get value from this JSON response into angular js object.

`[{"label":"Test","value":""," Test2":"","required":"mandatory","type":"text","typeemail":""}]`

into angularjs object, here is .html

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in searched = (coba | filter:customerid | filter:search ) | coba:(currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage |limitTo:viewby ">
    <td>
      <p>{{item.additionaldata_pay}}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

here is .js file

```
app.controller("cobacont", ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
      $scope.cari = function () {
        $http.get('...a='+$scope.month).then(function(response){
          $scope.coba = response.data; 
        });
      }  
}]);
```

Comment: Can you console.log(coba) in your controller ?  
Does your html target the right controller ?  
Should not you iterate on Controller.coba instead of searched ?

Comment: (90) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] . Here is The Result when i console.log(coba)

Comment: Can you do console.log(coba[0])? That will explain a lot about your data structure.

Comment: ya, but in the last record there is a json value like above. so i wanna get the value of that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('main-App', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

$scope.records = [];

$http.get("https://...a='+$scope.month")
  .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response.data);
     $scope.records = response.data;
  });
});
```

here is my html table

```
<tr dir-paginate="value in data | itemsPerPage:5" total-items="totalItems"  ng-repeat="user in records">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td >{{user.label}}</td>
    <td >{{user.value}}</td>
    <td>{{user.required}}</td>
    <td>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-data" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="selectedUser(user)">Edit</button>
        <button ng-click="DeleteUser(user)" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-data">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: or else u pass in method too->>>https://ids-fe1.com/MonitoringAPI/webresources/danaTrx?a='+$scope.month

Comment: i have tried what you said, with little bit approach. but it seems doesnt work. sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

It's best that you put all data processing in your controller. And leaving the HTML to display your data only.

So, in your controller, add another method that will do your search, filter, and pagination, and the result can then be used in your view.

```
$scope.getData = function () {
   var data = $filter('filter')($scope.coba, $scope.searchQuery);
   // do pagination here...
   return data;
}
```

Your HTML can then become something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in getData()">
    <td>
        <p ng-bind="item.additionaldata_pay"></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```